# Convergence of an event in Probability to zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $A_1,...A_N$ be sets with $A_i \subset \mathbb{R}$ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq N$, $ A = \bigcup_{i=1}^NA_i$ and let $ \mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on an appropriate probability space. The author now wants to prove the following lemma.

For every $ \epsilon >0 $ there exists a positive constant $ C_{\epsilon} < \infty$ such that

$$ \mathbb{P}(A) \leq C_{\epsilon} \cdot N^{- \epsilon} $$

Now he argues as follows:

$ \mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}({\bigcup_{i=1}^N}A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}(A_i) $ holds due to the sigma subadditivity of $\mathbb{P}$. Further as it is assumed that the $A_i´s$ are indistinguishable we have $ \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}(A_i) = N \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_1).$ So all in all:

$$ \mathbb{P}(A)\leq N \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_1) $$

Until here everything is fine but he now claims that it is sufficient to prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $C_{\epsilon}$ such that $ \mathbb{P}(A_1)\leq C_{\epsilon} N^{-\epsilon} $

But in my opinion this would yield:

$$ P(A) \leq N \mathbb{P}(A_1) \leq C_{\epsilon}\cdot N^{-\epsilon +1} $$

which could tend to infinity if $ \epsilon < 1$. But it is the goal of this lemma to prove convergence to zero. My first thought was that he could just define a new epsilon $\tilde{\epsilon}=-\epsilon +1$ and the lemma would be fulfilled. But this doesnt feel true. Any suggestions where my error in reasoning is?

Comment: You said: "But it is the goal of this lemma to prove convergence to zero." There is a problem here, because there's definitely no reason this would need to be true under the hypotheses you have supplied. For instance, let $A_1 = A_2 = \dots = (0, 1)$ on the probability space $(0,1)$ equipped with the Borel measure. Then we have $P(A) = 1 \not \to 0$. I'm guessing that you've omitted some additional context for the lemma....

Comment: Hi Aaron you are definitely right. I didnt want to overflow the Thread because the problem is not the lemma, the problem is why the lemma follows, if we prove $ \mathbb{P}(A_1) \leq C_{\epsilon}N^{-\epsilon}$.

Comment: Something is still off here, though. The lemma, as stated, is false as shown by the counterexample I provided. (For $\varepsilon > 0$, pick any $C_{\varepsilon}$; then $C_{\varepsilon} N^{-\varepsilon} \to 0$, and yet $P(A) = 1$ in my example.) There seem to be some additional hypotheses on the sets or something missing from this. One other telltale sign of this is that you say "as it is assumed the $A_i$'s are indistinguishable" halfway through, but that is something that isn't addressed or mentioned at all up until that point. So, I'm guessing some context is omitted.